# Why does my application enter break mode when I bind to a collection?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm, data-binding

I am currently trying to bind the `ItemSource` of my `ItemsControl` but for some reason it's throwing an issue saying that the application has entered break mode and I have no idea what the cause is, I really want to understand why it's entering breakmode, I tried debugging but it didn't really get me very far.

The goal was to create a custom `UserControl` and then being able to add them to a `ObservableCollection`with a button click. So creating a new one when the button has been clicked, unfortunatly I didn't get that far because this started happening.

So my question is, Why is it throwing that issue, is it something where it doesnt like the binding?

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding UserViewModel.Users}">
    <controls:UserCard/>
</ItemsControl>
```

And I've setup the DataContext like so

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = new BaseViewModel();
    }
}
```

And for the BaseViewModel, it looks like this

```
public class BaseViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    public UserViewModel UserViewModel { get; set; } = new UserViewModel();
}
```

And the UserViewModel looks like this

```
public class UserViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    public ObservableCollection<User> Users { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<User>();

    public UserViewModel()
    {

    }
}
```

With an ObservableObject like so

```
public class ObservableObject : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Comment: Good point! I'll make sure to clearify that next time I ask a question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `UserCard` control goes in the `ItemTemplate` of the `ItemsControl`:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding UserViewModel.Users}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <controls:UserCard/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Comment: Oh! So the `ItemsControl` needs a `ItemTemplate` specified?

Comment: Yes, if you want to present each item in the source collection using a `UserCard`.

Comment: Does that go for everything? Let's say I wanted to display a `TextBlock` control.
Would I have to explicitly use `ItemsControl.ItemTemplate` because how I look at it now is that I need to use `ItemsControl.ItemTemplate` to explicitly specify which type of data I am going to present

Comment: You would either define an `ItemTemplate` *or* set the `DisplayMemberPath` property to the name of the property of the data object that you want to display in the `ItemsControl`. You can't add items directly to the `ItemsControl` when you use the `ItemsSource` property.

Comment: Oh okay, I wonder why you can't add items to the `ItemsControl` from the `ItemSource` directly, nevertheless I'm going to get on MSDN and check it out! Thanks! I'll accept the answer as soon as I can.